# How the where clause will work for the date field in the teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to apply a where clause on the date field in the teredata, but it shows empty records. Below is the query used to get the data.

```
select * from table name where date = '2019-05-01'
```

Kindly suggest the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below format:

```
select * from table x where date = DATE '2019-05-01'
```

Check this [site](http://teradataforum.com/l081007a.htm)